# highfrequency AJjumptest error 'from' must be of length 1

Tags: r

I'd like to run the AJjumptest on a time series

```
head(l[[1]])
dim(l[[1]])
class(l[[1]])
AJjumptest(l, p=4 , k=2, align.by= "seconds", align.period = NULL, makeReturns= TRUE)
```

output:

```
> head(l[[1]])
                      [,1]
2015-06-29 09:30:00 163.98
2015-06-29 09:30:00 163.92
2015-06-29 09:30:00 163.98
2015-06-29 09:30:00 163.98
2015-06-29 09:30:00 163.98
2015-06-29 09:30:00 163.99
> dim(l[[1]])
[1] 29148     1
> class(l[[1]])
[1] "xts" "zoo"
> head(l[[1]])
                      [,1]
2015-06-29 09:30:00 163.98
2015-06-29 09:30:00 163.92
2015-06-29 09:30:00 163.98
2015-06-29 09:30:00 163.98
2015-06-29 09:30:00 163.98
2015-06-29 09:30:00 163.99
> dim(l[[1]])
[1] 29148     1
> class(l[[1]])
[1] "xts" "zoo"
> AJjumptest(l, p=4 , k=2, align.by= "seconds", align.period = NULL, makeReturns= TRUE)
Error in seq.default(start(ts), end(ts), by = tby) : 
  'from' must be of length 1

> traceback()
5: stop("'from' must be of length 1")
4: seq.default(start(ts), end(ts), by = tby)
3: base::seq(start(ts), end(ts), by = tby)
2: .aggregatets(pdata, on = "seconds", k = 1)
1: AJjumptest(l, p = 4, k = 2, align.by = "seconds", align.period = NULL, 
       makeReturns = TRUE)
```

any idea what that error means?